# Error 1004 - PrintOut method of worksheet class failed (after the creation of a pdf file)

Tags: excel, vba

I try to print an invoice after generating a PDF, but I get an error :

> ***PrintOut method of worksheet class failed***

The procedure of printing works perfectly as long as I didn't call pdf generate procedure.

I've tried to hide the sheets, activate, select again ... but nothing works. 
I'm a noob in VBA, so if someone can explain to me why I'm getting this error, it would be great.

```
Sub Print()
    Dim ImprCour As String
    Dim Impr2 As String
    ImprCour = Application.ActivePrinter
    Impr2 = "WorkCenter 6515"
    Application.ActivePrinter = Impr2
    Worksheets("Facture").Visible = True
    Worksheets("Retour").Visible = True
    Sheets(Array("Facture", "Retour")).Select
    MsgBox ActiveSheet.Name
    Worksheets(Array("Facture", "Retour")).PrintOut
    Worksheets("Facture").Visible = xlVeryHidden
    Worksheets("Retour").Visible = xlVeryHidden
    Worksheets("Facture").Visible = True
    Worksheets("Retour").Visible = True
    Application.ActivePrinter = ImprCour
End Sub

Sub Pdf_And_Print()
Sheets(Array("Facture", "Retour")).Select
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    FileName:="/Users/stefland/Desktop/Projets/Pro/...-v.03/.../.../.../.../..." & "_" & Range("H21").Value & ".pdf", _
    OpenAfterPublish:=True, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=False, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    From:=1, To:=2
    Print
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Sub wsPrint(sh As Worksheet)
    Dim ImprCour As String
    Dim Impr2 As String
    ImprCour = Application.ActivePrinter
    Impr2 = "WorkCenter 6515"
    Application.ActivePrinter = Impr2
    sh.Visible = True
    MsgBox sh.Name
    sh.PrintOut
    'sh.Visible = xlVeryHidden
    Application.ActivePrinter = ImprCour
End Sub

Sub Pdf_And_Print()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    For Each sh In Sheets(Array("Facture", "Retour"))
        sh.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
            Filename:="/Users/stefland/Desktop/Projets/Pro/...-v.03/.../.../.../.../..." & "_" & sh.Range("H21").Value & ".pdf", _
            OpenAfterPublish:=True, _
            IncludeDocProperties:=False, _
            IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
            Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
            From:=1, To:=2
            wsPrint sh
    Next sh
End Sub
```

Comment: Thx Nathan for your help.
I get the same error at this line : `Sheets(shArr(s)).PrintOut`

Comment: I forgot to make it visible first. Try the above edited version.

Comment: Nice try, but now it's at the line : `sh.PrintOut`.

Comment: Is your sheet protected?

Comment: No she's not. I just realized that when I paste your code, the code works fine (he print 4 times). But when I use the real Filename ... error.

Comment: Update : I forgot to mention that I was on macOS. When I use the sub to create a pdf, excel generate a pdf, but when I do a cmd+p, he print the invoice with white margin. So maybe the problem come from here.

Comment: I think the key is doing one sheet at a time.

Comment: I have updated my answer using your original structure, but adding a loop to export and print one sheet at a time.

Comment: I get "Object Doesn't Support this Property or Method" when I call wsPrint(sh)(Pdf_And_Print)

Comment: I forgot It should not be in parentheses.

Comment: Error 1004 on sh.PrintOut again. I'm sure the pb come from here : 
https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/some-characters-textbox-lost-convert.html

But we can't change the print quality on excel macos.

Comment: You can change PrintQuality (sh.PageSetup.PrintQuality = 600), but I don't think that would cause an error. Two days ago, you said "No she's not. I just realized that when I paste your code, the code works fine (he print 4 times). But when I use the real Filename ... error". Could you elaborate?

Comment: Because a video is better than a thousand words :
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1I-O-L66hYYG_nQZVnZcYrzUYxLMnTQfQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I'm guessing ExportAsFixedFormat fails because the path isn't quite right and/or sh.Range("H21") has an unexpected/invalid value. It looks like you switched to a different workbook when it worked, no?

Comment: I've change the path and remove the Range, but nothing to do. I've tried with the two different verison of my invoice. (I switched but it's the same workbook).

Comment: But it's surprising, he print two times the same sheet.